# Appending data in an Excel file

Tags: java, excel, jexcelapi

I am trying to write a program that will append data to an Excel file in Java. I got up to the following code. But it rewrites the contents in the Excel file, not appending to it. Please help me to complete this.

```
public class jExcel
{
    static WritableWorkbook workbook;
    public static void main(String args[])throws Exception
    {
        workbook = Workbook.createWorkbook((new File("D:\\0077\\my2.xls")));
        WritableSheet sheet = workbook.createSheet("First Sheett",1);
        Label label = new Label(5,2,"ssssssssss");
        sheet.addCell(label);
        workbook.write();
        workbook.close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

//WRITE IN XLS

```
    WritableWorkbook workbook = Workbook.createWorkbook(new File("D:\\output.xls"));
    WritableSheet sheet = workbook.createSheet("First Sheet", 0);
    Label label = new Label(0, 2, "A label record"); 
    sheet.addCell(label);
    workbook.write(); 
    workbook.close();

    //MODIFY XLS

    Workbook workbook1 = Workbook.getWorkbook(new File("D:\\output.xls"));
    WritableWorkbook copy = Workbook.createWorkbook(new File("D:\\output.xls"), workbook1);
    WritableSheet sheet2 = copy.getSheet(0); 
    //WritableCell cell = sheet2.getWritableCell(5, 2); 

    copy.write();
    copy.close();
```

Answer (score 5):

Instead of using `createWorkbook` use "`getWorkbook(java.io.File file)` " to get an existing Excel.
Then use `getSheet(int index)` to retrieve the appropriate sheet.

To the sheet you retrieved above use "`addCell(WritableCell cell)` " to append cells to the sheet.

```
Workbook workbook = Workbook.getWorkbook(new File(""D:\\0077\\my2.xls""));
WritableWorkbook copy = Workbook.createWorkbook(new File("output.xls"), workbook);
WritableSheet sheet2 = copy.getSheet(1); 
Label label = new Label(5,2,"ssssssssss"); 
sheet2.addCell(label);
```

You will find a lot of examples here.
http://www.andykhan.com/jexcelapi/tutorial.html

Comment: i have tryed but not getting. can you edit the code and send .pls

Answer (score 1):

After opening the `workbook` from file, do like this:

```
WritableWorkbook copy = Workbook.createWorkbook(
   new File(""D:\\0077\\my2_copy.xls""), 
   workbook
);
```

You will get a copy of the workbook opened. Do the changes you need in that copy and save it instead.