# Writing data to excel in existing sheet every time

Tags: java, excel, jexcelapi

Could someone please help me how to append data to excel sheet. I have tried with using jxl.jar file .

But every time it creates new sheet. I want to use the existing excel sheet and need to append my data every time my test runs.

Here is the code I'm using, that creates a new sheet everytime:

```
   Workbook aWorkBook = Workbook.getWorkbook(new File("C:/Automation/Testdata.xls"));
   WritableWorkbook aCopy = Workbook.createWorkbook(new File("C:/Automation/TestResult.xls"), aWorkBook);
   WritableSheet aCopySheet = aCopy.getSheet(0);//index of the needed sheet
   jxl.write.Label anotherWritableCell =  new jxl.write.Label(row+36, col ,"Pass");
   aCopySheet.addCell(anotherWritableCell);
   aCopy.write();
   aCopy.close();
```

Comment: What does this have to do with Selenium?

Comment: It is with writing to existing excel, please help

Answer (score 0):

The problem is unrelated to Selenium. Your issue is with correctly appending data to an Excel sheet. The problem has been discussed before and solved here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9389397/170781.