# Need to write Results in Xls

Tags: java, apache-poi

I need to write test cases name and results in xls file or csv file. I have Used an existing file and writing the result in existing file it returns NULL pointer exception on line ***  cell=row.getCell(0); ***

Given below my code..

```
  package com.testCases;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;

import com.test.utility.PrintResultinExcel;
import com.test.utility.ReadExcelSheet;
import com.test.utility.clearText;
import com.test.utility.clickEvent;
import com.test.utility.globalVariables;
import com.test.utility.selectCheckbox;
import com.test.utility.text;
import com.test.utility.verifyText;
import com.test.utility.writeExcel;

public class SQLInject extends globalVariables{
    public static void sqlinjection() throws InterruptedException, IOException{
        ArrayList<HashMap> data = ReadExcelSheet.readExcel("Sheet1");
        int size = data.size();     
        System.out.println("Total Number of Keywords: "+size);      
        for(int i=0;i<=size-1;i++){
        clickEvent.clickAt("allcustomers_linkText");
        Thread.sleep(2000);
        clickEvent.clickAt("sqlquery_xpath");       
        Thread.sleep(2000);
        String keyword = data.get(i).get("Keywords").toString();
        text.enterText("sql_id", keyword);
        clickEvent.clickAt("sqlsearchbutton_id");
        verifyText.verify("SQL statement does NOT contain valid  keywords.");
        String result="PASS";   
        PrintResultinExcel.excelLog(keyword, result, i);
        }
    }

}
```

Utility File:

```
package com.test.utility;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;

import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFCell;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFRow;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell;

public class PrintResultinExcel extends globalVariables {


    public static void excelLog(String keyword, String result, int rowNum) {
        try {
            FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream(new File("D:\\testexcel.xls"));

            HSSFWorkbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook(file);
            HSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);
            // Find empty cell
            HSSFRow row = sheet.getRow(rowNum);
            Cell cell = null;
            cell=row.getCell(0);
            cell.setCellValue(keyword);
            cell=row.getCell(1);
            cell.setCellValue(result);
            // Update the value of cell

            file.close();

            FileOutputStream outFile = new FileOutputStream(new File("D:\\testexcel.xls"));
            workbook.write(outFile);
            outFile.close();

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    }
```

Comment: Don't create a new file; just add new data or a new workbook to the existing file.

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5509073/appending-data-in-an-excel-file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is working fine for me to update the existing sheet.

```
   public class writeExcel extends globalVariables {
        public static void write(int row, int column, String result) throws InvalidFormatException {


            try {
                InputStream inp = new FileInputStream("/SQLInjection.xlsx");
                org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Workbook wb = WorkbookFactory.create(inp);
                Sheet sheet = wb.getSheet("Results");
              //  Sheet sheet = wb.getSheet(0);
                Row sheetRow = sheet.getRow(row);
                Cell cell = sheetRow.getCell(column);
                if (cell == null) {
                    cell = sheetRow.createCell(column);
                    cell.setCellType(Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING);
                }
                cell.setCellType(Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING);
                cell.setCellValue(result);
                FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream("/SQLInjection.xlsx");
                wb.write(fileOut);
                fileOut.close();
              //  System.out.println("Results updated in Excel Sheet");

            } catch (IOException ex) {

            } 
        }
     /*  public static void main(String[] args) throws BiffException, IOException, InvalidFormatException {
            for (int i = 1;i <= 10;i++) {
                //excelLog("Exec" + i, "PASS" + i, i);
                System.out.println("Test");
                write(i,1,"Test", "PASS");
            } 
       }*/
    }
```

Comment: Thanks to all for giving inputs.

Answer (score 1):

Add the data to the `WorkBook` and keep it in memory. Once the data addition is done, then write it to the file.

**Sample Code**

```
package com.test.utility;

import java.io.FileOutputStream;

import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFCell;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFRow;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook;

public class writeExcel extends globalVariables {

    private static String dest = "D:\\testexcel.xls";
    private static HSSFWorkbook myWorkBook = new HSSFWorkbook();
    private static HSSFSheet mySheet = myWorkBook.createSheet();

    public static void excelLog(String keyword, String result, int rowNum) {

        HSSFRow myRow = null;
        HSSFCell myCell = null;

        myRow = mySheet.createRow(rowNum);

        myCell = myRow.createCell(0);
        myCell.setCellValue(keyword);
        myCell = myRow.createCell(1);
        myCell.setCellValue(result);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        for (int i = 1;i <= 100;i++) {
            excelLog("Exec" + i, "PASS" + i, i);
        }

        try {
            FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(dest);
            myWorkBook.write(out);
            out.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

**EDIT:**

It might be possible that you file/workBook/Sheet/row/cell does not exists. So it is necessary to handle all the cases.

Check the documentation of [HSSFSheet.getRow(int rowNum)](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/hssf/usermodel/HSSFSheet.html#getRow%28int%29).

Here is updated code to do the same:

```
package com.test.utility;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;

import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFRow;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell;


public class writeExcel {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
            excelLog("Exec" + i, "PASS" + i, i);
        }
    }

    public static void excelLog(String keyword, String result, int rowNum) {
        String fileName = "testexcel.xls";
        try {
            File f = new File(fileName);
            HSSFWorkbook workbook = getWorkBook(f);
            HSSFSheet sheet = getSheet(workbook);

            HSSFRow row = getRow(sheet, rowNum);
            // Find empty cell
            Cell cell = null;
            cell = getCell(row, 0);
            cell.setCellValue(keyword);
            cell = getCell(row, 1);
            cell.setCellValue(result);
            // Update the value of cell

            workbook.close();

            FileOutputStream outFile = new FileOutputStream(new File(fileName));
            workbook.write(outFile);
            outFile.close();

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    private static Cell getCell(HSSFRow row, int cellNum) {
        Cell cell = row.getCell(cellNum);
        if (cell == null) {
            cell = row.createCell(cellNum);
        }
        return cell;
    }

    private static HSSFRow getRow(HSSFSheet sheet, int rowNum) {
        HSSFRow row = sheet.getRow(rowNum);
        if (row == null) {
            row = sheet.createRow(rowNum);
        }
        return row;
    }

    private static HSSFSheet getSheet(HSSFWorkbook workbook) {
        HSSFSheet sheet = null;
        try {
            sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            sheet = workbook.createSheet();
        }
        return sheet;
    }

    private static HSSFWorkbook getWorkBook(File f) throws IOException {
        FileInputStream file = null;
        HSSFWorkbook workbook = null;
        if (f.exists()) {
            file = new FileInputStream(f);
            workbook = new HSSFWorkbook(file);
        } else {
            workbook = new HSSFWorkbook();
        }

        return workbook;
    }
}
```

Comment: I have updated the code which fixes NPE and will work even if XLS file doesn't exists.