# Write results in existing excel in SOAPUI Groovy Fails

Tags: excel, groovy, soapui

I have a requirement to write a results (Pass/Fail) in the same excel sheet where the script reads the parameter in a FOR loop. It is throwing an error:

```
org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.typehandling.GroovyCastException: Cannot cast object 'jxl.read.biff.WorkbookParser@3da0525b' with class 'jxl.read.biff.WorkbookParser' to class 'jxl.write.WritableWorkbook' error at line: 16
```

My code:

```js
import jxl.*;
import jxl.write.*;
import java.io.*;
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper

//Get project path

def groovyUtils = new com.eviware.soapui.support.GroovyUtils(context)

def projectPath = groovyUtils.projectPath

def testCaseName = testRunner.testCase.name

//Read excel file and get the input value
 
 WritableWorkbook xlwb = Workbook.getWorkbook(new File ("${projectPath}\\${testCaseName}.xls"))
 Sheet inputxlsh = xlwb.getSheet(0)
 inputRowCount = inputxlsh.getRows();
 WritableSheet outputxlsh = xlwb.getSheet(1)
 outputRowCount = outputxlsh.getRows();

 log.info "Executing Test Case " + testCaseName
 log.info "Total records to send API request to webservice from the file : " +  inputRowCount -1
 
 for (i=0;i<inputRowCount-1;i++)
 {
  Cell requestParam1 = inputxlsh.getCell(0,i+1)
  affkey = requestParam1.getContents()

  Cell requestParam2 = inputxlsh.getCell(1,i+1)
  etid = requestParam2.getContents()
    
  def soapTestCase = context.testCase

//Set the request property value (Parameter)

  requestPropertyVariable = soapTestCase.getTestStepByName("requestProperty")
  requestPropertyVariable.setPropertyValue("affkey",affkey)
  requestPropertyVariable.setPropertyValue("etid",etid)
  
  log.info "Reading record " + (i+1) + " from input file"
  log.info "Sending request with affkey " + affkey
  log.info "Sending request with etid " + etid
  
//Post a request to webservice

  def responseContent = testRunner.runTestStepByName("showetidRequest").getResponse()
  def responseText = responseContent.getContentAsString()

//Save the output file

  def fileObj = new File("${projectPath}\\API_Response\\${testRunner.testCase.name}\\${etid}_Response.txt")
  saveToFile(fileObj, responseText)

//Get the response value

  JsonSlurper jsonResponseContent = new JsonSlurper()

  def jsonResponseObject = jsonResponseContent.parseText(responseText)

//Validate results

   Cell headerParam1 = outputxlsh.getCell(0,0)
   Cell headerParam2 = outputxlsh.getCell(1,0)
   Cell headerParam3 = outputxlsh.getCell(2,0)
   Cell headerParam4 = outputxlsh.getCell(3,0)
   Cell headerParam5 = outputxlsh.getCell(4,0)
   Cell headerParam6 = outputxlsh.getCell(5,0)
   
  for (k = 0; k < outputRowCount-1; k++) { 
   Cell responseParam1 = outputxlsh.getCell(0,k+1)
   Cell responseParam2 = outputxlsh.getCell(1,k+1)
   Cell responseParam3 = outputxlsh.getCell(2,k+1)
   Cell responseParam4 = outputxlsh.getCell(3,k+1)
   Cell responseParam5 = outputxlsh.getCell(4,k+1)
   Cell responseParam6 = outputxlsh.getCell(5,k+1)
   
   expectedAffiliatesWithContent = responseParam1.getContents()
   expectedEntityName = responseParam2.getContents()
   expectedName = responseParam3.getContents()
   expectedSaleMessageId = responseParam4.getContents()
   expectedTitle = responseParam5.getContents()
   expectedetid = responseParam6.getContents()
    
   if(etid==expectedetid){

   responseAffiliatesWithContent = jsonResponseObject.AffiliatesWithContent.getAt(0).getAt(0)
   responseEntityName = jsonResponseObject.Genre.EntityName.getAt(0)
   responseName = jsonResponseObject.Genre.Name.getAt(0)
   responseSaleMessageId = jsonResponseObject.SaleMessage.Id.getAt(0)
   responseTitle = jsonResponseObject.Title.getAt(0)
         
    log.info responseAffiliatesWithContent
    log.info responseEntityName
    log.info responseName
    log.info responseSaleMessageId
    log.info responseTitle

    if (responseAffiliatesWithContent==expectedAffiliatesWithContent&&responseEntityName==expectedEntityName&&responseName==expectedName&&responseSaleMessageId==expectedSaleMessageId&&
     responseTitle==expectedTitle)
     {
     log.info "The data is matched for record " + (k +1) + " hence test case passed "
                     Label l = new Label(7, k +1, "Pass");
                     outputxlsh.addCell(l);
                     xlwb.write();      
     }
     else {
     log.info "The data is matched for record " + (k +1) + " hence test case failed "
     }
   }
  }
  }

//Clear Property
 requestPropertyVariable.setPropertyValue("affkey","")
 requestPropertyVariable.setPropertyValue("etid","")
 
//Write file method

 def saveToFile(fileObj, content) {
  if (!fileObj.parentFile.exists()) {
          fileObj.parentFile.mkdirs()
     }
  fileObj.write(content) 
      log.info "Response for etid " + etid + " is stored in " + "${etid}_Response.txt"
  assert fileObj.exists(), "${fileObj.name} not created"
 }
```

Comment: Are you ok to write result in comma separated file (.csv) which you will be able to open it in excel?

Comment: http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/JavaExcel/article.html - see if this helps.

Comment: No Rao.. As the excel contains graphs for test case status based on the value populated in the pass / fail column, we cannot convert that file to csv

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have achieved the requirement based on below code

```
    def inptDataWb = new HSSFWorkbook(xlwb);
    def inputxlsh = inptDataWb.getSheetAt(2);
    wrtResult = outputxlsh.getRow(k+1).getCell(3);
    wrtResult.setCellValue("P");
    wrtResult = outputxlsh.getRow(k+1).getCell(5);
    wrtResult.setCellValue("");
    inptDataWb.write(xlOwb);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want a write able copy call `createWorkbook` function

```
WritableWorkbook xlwb = Workbook.createWorkbook(new File ("${projectPath}\\${testCaseName}.xls"))
```

If you don't want write able copy save in `Workbook` object instead

```
Workbook workbook = Workbook.getWorkbook((new File ("${projectPath}\\${testCaseName}.xls"))
```

Comment: Thanks for your comments. But I want to write pass or fail result in the existing file instead of write it in the new file

Comment: Can anyone help me on this please?

Comment: For appending see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5509073/appending-data-in-an-excel-file